# for iteration and over time

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have one file text spiltted by line, and two lists with items exctracted from the file text. the task is to create a dict of the items in the two list which occur in the same line in the file text. this is the code

```
list1 = [items] ### about 114,5 kB
list2 = [items] ### about 115,5 kB
file_text = file text splitted by lines ### about 190,5 kB


dict_one =  defaultdict(set)
for line in file_text:
    for x in list1:
        for xx in list2:
            if x in line and xx in line:
                dict_one[x].add(xx)   
print (dict_one.items())
```

My problem is the over time for the iteration. Can someone suggest another way with less time for iteration. Thanks

Comment: Could you provide a simple example? Not the entire file, just a few lines and items. As I understand it now, you want to have one entry in the dict whenever two items from the list appear in a line together?

Comment: It should get somewhat faster if you separately check for each line if it contains a word of `list1` or `list2`, respectively. You'll store that in two boolean numpy arrays and then perform a logical AND (`&`). Depending on the real use case, this should go much faster.

Comment: @gho, i would try Carsten's approach - it sounds promising...

Comment: @Carsten, can you formulate it in one answer?

Comment: Is this a pure text search? Sample data would be very helpful. Regardless, you might consider building a regex out of the two input lists. It would take a while to build, but should perform much faster.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you are checking all the items in `list2` again and again for each value of `list1`, but whether those are in `line` is independent of whether the current value from `list1` is in `line`. By simply rearranging the loops a bit and reusing the matches for `list2` for each match from `list1` this should get a lot faster.

```
for line in file_text:
    x_in_line = [x for x in list1 if x in line]
    if x_in_line:
        y_in_line = [y for y in list2 if y in line]
        for x in x_in_line:
            dict_one[x].update(y_in_line)
```

If `file`text`has _n_ items,`list1`_k_ items, and`list2` *j* items, then your algorithm would have complexity of O(n*k*j), while this one should have only O(n(k+j)).

Another optimization might be to split the line and turn it into a set of words, but depending on your data this might or might not work.

```
    line_as_set = set(line.split())
    x_in_line = [x for x in list1 if x in line_as_set]
```

Or, since you extracted the items in `list1` and `list2` from `file_text`, you could just use the same function(s) you used for extracting the words from the file and apply it to just the current line, without using `list1` and `list2` at all.

```
for line in file_text:
    x_in_line = extract_values_1(line)
    if x_in_line:
        y_in_line = extract_values_2(line)
        for x in x_in_line:
            dict_one[x].update(y_in_line)
```

If the file has very many, short lines, then this is probably faster than checking all the words in `list1` and `list2` just to find the very few that appeared in that particular line.

Comment: In my case, since the items of the two lists are extracted from the file text, so x_in_line = [x for x in list1 if x in line] = x_in_line

Comment: I mean that  both x_in_line and y_in_line are terms extracted from the same file, so your  [x for x in list1 if x in line]  = list1

Comment: @gho Note that the list `x_in_line` will only contain those items that are in _the current line_, whereas `list1` and `list2` contain items that are found somewhere in the entire file.

Comment: @gho So, does this work for you? Is the output not what you expected, or is it still not fast enough?

Comment: It  is still not fast enough

Comment: @gho In this case, please provide more information about the data: What kind of data (numbers, sentences, DNA sequences, ...), how are `list1` and `list2` generated, etc. Best would be to provide a short example dataset for all three lists.

Answer (score 0):

[multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) can give you a NUMBER_OF_CORES times speed up

Part of an example code...

```
 from multiprocessing import Pool

 pool = Pool(NUMBER_OF_CORES)
 pool.map()

 def f(args):
     files, list1, list2 = args
     dict_one =  defaultdict(set)
     for line in file_text:
         for x in list1:
             for xx in list2:
                 if x in line and xx in line:
                     dict_one[x].add(xx) 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Pool(NUMBER_OF_CORES)
    chunk_size= len(files) //NUMBER_OF_CORES
    print(p.map(f, [(files[i*chunk_size:(i+1)*chunk_size], list1, list2) for i in range(NUMBER_OF_CORES)]))
```

Comment: But this does not reduce the overall complexity of the algorithm, which in its current form is much higher than needed.